# How can I add static text as Footer at the bottom of the GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a Foot Note at the bottom of the Grid. but from the below code snippet, I am seeing footnote at the bottom but it is coming in the empty columns. I mean to say if I have 4 columns in the Grid, the Foot Note is displaying after the 4th column. this should not happen. Ideally, the footnote will starts from the first column until the end of the grid. (as a row)
Any suggestions, please?

```
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" BorderWidth="0" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" Width="100%" runat="server">
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                             <asp:GridView ID="_gridView1" runat="server"  
                                                EnableViewState="false" ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="false" EnableFixedHeader="true" Width="100%" 
                                                 AutoGenerateColumns="false" >

                                                 <Columns>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="12%" ItemStyle-Width="12%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate >
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_LineName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LineName") %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                      <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity0" HeaderText="Entity0" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityZero" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName0") %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                         </asp:TemplateField>
                                                         <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity1" HeaderText="Entity1" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityOne" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName1") %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                         </asp:TemplateField>
                                                         <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity2" HeaderText="Entity2"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                      <asp:Label ID="_entityTwo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName2") %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity3" HeaderText="Entity3" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityThree" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName3") %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                         <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity4" HeaderText="Entity4" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityFour" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName4")  %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                      <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity5" HeaderText="Entity5" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityFive" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName5")  %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                      <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity6" HeaderText="Entity6" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entitySix" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName6")  %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                      <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity7" HeaderText="Entity7" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entitySeven" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName7")  %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                      <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity8" HeaderText="Entity8" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityEight" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName8")  %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                      <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity9" HeaderText="Entity9" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityNine" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName9")  %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                      <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity10" HeaderText="Entity10" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityTen" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName10")  %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField ID="footer" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label id="lblFooter"  runat="server">'Last Review Date' indicates the date on which an Issuer Rating was last formally reviewed within a twelve-month period or when a Credit Rating Action was last published. <br /></asp:Label>
                                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    </Columns>
                                            </asp:GridView>

                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
```

Comment: You should add your footerTemplate on the first templateField only, then in code behind _gridView1.FooterRow.Cells(0).ColumnSpan = 12 and remove all the others cells from the footer row _gridView1.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(1), _gridView1.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(2) .... _gridView1.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(11)

Comment: footer templates are specific to each column (i.e. within each template field). So you have to put the footer specifically on the column you want.

Comment: P.S. why are you wrapping the GridView inside an `<asp:Table>`?? Both that and the Gridview will render a HTML `<table>` when the page is sent to the browser. So then you will have a table within a table - seems a bit pointless, as well as not being semantic (i.e. not meaningful markup).

Comment: The footer template is specific to each column in the grid view. The easiest solution for you is to add a table row at the end of grid view and add foot note there instead of using Grid view footer template

Comment: @Melvin: I tried earlier what you are suggesting, but when we expand the widget, we are seeing more white space btw the foot note and the GridView. so I would like to have the foot note inside the Grid.

Comment: @B. Lec: I did as per your suggestion, now the foot note is coming fine. but only problem is  it is appearing as a row in the Grid view. It is not appearing as Foot Note. can we remove the last line under the foot note?

Comment: I don't understand which line you talk about under the foot note. footerTemplate is always rendered as a new row at the end of the grid. Perhaps remove  the <br/> tag in the lblFooter label and add some css styles